# Resize tikzpicture in input

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, input, xcoffins

I'm attempting to insert a tikspicture into my text. However, rather than having the code in actual document, I bring it in as an input, such as this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]

\input{Grafikk/ValuesToOpinion}

\caption{Lorem Ipsum}
\label{Dolor Sit Amet}
\end{figure}
```

Doing it in this was will make it considerably easier if I want to change something about the figure, and makes the document a lot cleaner. The picture becomes somewhat larger than I would like, and goes outside the page. I can't seem to find a way to rescale it either. Using `\input{}` within a `\includregraphics{}` just returns an error, as it expects a regular picture format. I've also attempted to use `\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.5pt}}` in the preamble, but that gives no change at all. Anyone got any tips?

MWE:
Document:

```
 \documentclass{report}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
 \kant[5]

 \begin{figure}[h]
 \input{tixzfigure}   
  \label{something}
  \caption{something else}  
   \end{figure}
   Dolor sit amet
  \end{document}
```

tikz-figure:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
 

    %Shape: Triangle [id:dp09448679081661204] 
    \draw   (316.15,13) -- (635.3,161.2) -- (-3,161.2) -- cycle ;
    %Shape: Rectangle [id:dp80163133792419] 
     \draw   (-7.7,25) -- (655.3,25) -- (655.3,65) -- (-7.7,65) -- cycle ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Also, all the tikz code is from this website https://www.mathcha.io/editor

Comment: I think that something as \scalebox or \resizebox should work.

Comment: You can define common `tikzset` in preamble of the your document, where you define styles as line widths, scaling etc. Furthermore, by naming of `\tikzset`s, you can in zikzpictures  call which of them they should use. I will not use any scaling, since it can destroy consistency of used fonts in document and in image.

Comment: @eric gabo ekeberg nilsen Could you please provide a tikz  example that behaves as you explain in the question?

Comment: @Zarko, scale on tikzpictures does not affect text size, unless you force it to do so, using things such as `every node/.style={scale=0.6}`

Comment: @Jes, we have problem with (mis)understanding. I respond on the use of  the `scalebox` etc. I'm very well aware that scaling inside image doesn't scale text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having explored the topic of scaling, other -quite obvious- options to fit a figure larger than the text area are:

(1) Use the landscape mode, or

(2) use the margins.

For #2 I use the package `xcoffins`. The material (text, images, tikzfigures, tables, etc.) are place in special boxes that can be attached to other similar boxes in may ways, including the addition of X & Y offsets  (applied as `(X offset, Y offset)` by the `Join` command).

This second facility allows for an easy placement of the material anywhere on the physical page.

The boxes behaves as a text object, so they are not a float, and are typeset at the current insertion point.

The same package allows for rotation of the boxes, as it is shown in the second page.

[image: x1]

[image: x2]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcoffins}

\NewCoffin\Framex
\NewCoffin\tikzFig

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
        
As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things
in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
used as a canon for our understanding.


\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \input{qtikzfigure2}   
    \label{something}
    \caption{something else out of page}  
\end{figure}

Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of
the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time.
Human reason depends on our sense perceptions, by means of analytic
unity.

\bigskip

\SetHorizontalCoffin\tikzFig{%
\input{qtikzfigure2}    
}   
        
\JoinCoffins*\Framex[l,t]\tikzFig[l,t](-60pt,0pt) % shift towards left margin
\noindent\TypesetCoffin\Framex
\vspace*{\CoffinTotalHeight\tikzFig}    
\captionof{figure}{Input from file and X offset added to center}

\bigskip
    
As is shown in the writings of Aristotle, the things
in themselves (and it remains a mystery why this is the case) are a
representation of time. Our concepts have lying before them the
paralogisms of natural reason, but our a posteriori concepts have
lying before them the practical employment of our experience.

\newpage

\SetHorizontalCoffin\Framex{}

\RotateCoffin\tikzFig{90}
\JoinCoffins*\Framex[l,b]\tikzFig[r,vc](\textwidth/2,0pt) % centering 
\noindent\TypesetCoffin\Framex
\vspace*{\CoffinTotalHeight\tikzFig}    
\captionof{figure}{Input from file and X offset added to center plus rotated}


\end{document}
```

The file `qtikzfigure2.tex` used contains the tikzfigure provided by the OP with a  rectangle and a triangle overflowing the text area when inserted at the left margin (Fig. 1).

Comment: So any proper answer will depend of the context: text, math, lines, etc used in the original figure plus one column, two column, ....

Comment: And that's why one should doble check it .Seems there was some difference between the actuall code and the MWE I diden't notice. Added a new one now, that gives the proper result on my computer at least.